# Cakephp 3.4 always saving primary key as NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to insert to my inwards shipments table but I want to use my own primary key (release_note) not sql auto increment. 
So I made the release_note field visible with

```
echo $this->Form->input('release_note', ['type' => 'text', 'id' => 'note']);
```

but every time I try add a new inward shipment the text I put into this input is never saved and submitted into the sql query therefore always defaulting the value to NULL.

This is my InwardsShipmentsTable

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * InwardShipments Model
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\SuppliersTable|\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Suppliers
 * @property \App\Model\Table\ShippingMethodsTable|\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $ShippingMethods
 * @property \App\Model\Table\OrdersTable|\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Orders
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable|\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Users
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\InwardShipment get($primaryKey, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\InwardShipment newEntity($data = null, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\InwardShipment[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\InwardShipment|bool save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\InwardShipment patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\InwardShipment[] patchEntities($entities, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\InwardShipment findOrCreate($search, callable $callback = null, $options = [])
 */
class InwardShipmentsTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('inward_shipments');
        $this->setDisplayField('release_note');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('release_note');

        $this->belongsTo('Suppliers', [
            'foreignKey' => 'supplier_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('ShippingMethods', [
            'foreignKey' => 'shipping_method_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Orders', [
            'foreignKey' => 'order_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('release_note', 'create');

        $validator
            ->date('date')
            ->allowEmpty('date');

        $validator
            ->numeric('freight_amount')
            ->allowEmpty('freight_amount');

        $validator
            ->numeric('weight')
            ->allowEmpty('weight');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('supplier_invoice_number');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('supplier_release_note');

        $validator
            ->numeric('invoice_total')
            ->allowEmpty('invoice_total');

        $validator
            ->integer('comercial')
            ->allowEmpty('comercial');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('consignment_no');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('notes');

        $validator
            ->integer('dim_l')
            ->allowEmpty('dim_l');

        $validator
            ->integer('dim_w')
            ->allowEmpty('dim_w');

        $validator
            ->integer('dim_h')
            ->allowEmpty('dim_h');

        $validator
            ->numeric('volume')
            ->allowEmpty('volume');

        $validator
            ->numeric('volumetric')
            ->allowEmpty('volumetric');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('freight_invoice_no');

        $validator
            ->numeric('USD_exch_rate')
            ->allowEmpty('USD_exch_rate');

        $validator
            ->numeric('freight_costs')
            ->allowEmpty('freight_costs');

        $validator
            ->numeric('customs_costs')
            ->allowEmpty('customs_costs');

        $validator
            ->integer('freight_added')
            ->allowEmpty('freight_added');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('certification_type');

        $validator
            ->numeric('bank_charges')
            ->allowEmpty('bank_charges');

        $validator
            ->numeric('other_charges')
            ->allowEmpty('other_charges');

        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['supplier_id'], 'Suppliers'));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['shipping_method_id'], 'ShippingMethods'));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['order_id'], 'Orders'));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['user_id'], 'Users'));

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

This is my InwardsShipmentsController add method.

```
public function add()
    {

        $inwardShipment = $this->InwardShipments->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $inwardShipment = $this->InwardShipments->patchEntity($inwardShipment, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->InwardShipments->save($inwardShipment)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The {0} has been saved.', 'Inward Shipment'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The {0} could not be saved. Please, try again.', 'Inward Shipment'));



            }
        }
```

and this is my add.ctp there's some script for setting the release_note at the bottom

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">    
<?php use Cake\Routing\Router; ?>
<section class="content-header">
  <h1>
    Inward Shipment
    <small><?= __('Add') ?></small>
  </h1>
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li>
    <?= $this->Html->link('<i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> '.__('Back'), ['action' => 'index'], ['escape' => false]) ?>
    </li>
  </ol>
</section>

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- left column -->
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <!-- general form elements -->
      <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title"><?= __('Form') ?></h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <!-- form start -->
        <?= $this->Form->create($inwardShipment, array('role' => 'form')) ?>
          <div class="box-body">
          <div class="col-md-6">
          <?php

            echo $this->Form->input('release_note', ['type' => 'text', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'id' => 'note']);
            echo $this->Form->input('date', ['empty' => true, 'default' => '', 'class' => 'datepicker form-control', 'type' => 'text']);
            echo $this->Form->input('supplier_id', ['type' => 'hidden', 'id'=>'id']);
            echo $this->Form->input('supplier_name', ['type' => 'text', 'empty' => true, 'id' => 'supplier']);
            echo $this->Form->input('shipping_method_id', ['options' => $shippingMethods, 'empty' => true]);
            echo $this->Form->input('weight');
            echo $this->Form->input('freight_invoice_no');
            echo $this->Form->input('supplier_invoice_number');
            echo $this->Form->input('supplier_release_note');
            echo $this->Form->input('order_id', ['options' => $orders, 'empty' => true]);
            echo $this->Form->input('consignment_no');
            echo $this->Form->input('notes');
            echo $this->Form->input('user_id', ['options' => $users, 'empty' => true]);
            echo $this->Form->input('certification_type');
            echo $this->Form->input('comercial', ['type' => 'checkbox', 'id'=>'comercial']);
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('dim_l');
            echo $this->Form->input('dim_w');
            echo $this->Form->input('dim_h');
            echo $this->Form->input('volume');
            echo $this->Form->input('volumetric');
            echo $this->Form->input('freight_costs');
            echo $this->Form->input('bank_charges', ['id' => 'bank']);
            echo $this->Form->input('other_charges');
            echo $this->Form->input('customs_costs', ['id' => 'customs']);
            echo $this->Form->input('freight_amount');
            echo $this->Form->input('invoice_total');
            echo $this->Form->input('USD_exch_rate', ['id' => 'rate']);
            echo $this->Form->input('freight_added', ['type' => 'checkbox']);
          ?>
          </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
          <div class="box-footer">
            <?= $this->Form->button(__('Save')) ?>
          </div>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

        <?php
$this->Html->css([
    'AdminLTE./plugins/datepicker/datepicker3',
  ],
  ['block' => 'css']);

$this->Html->script([
  'AdminLTE./plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask',
  'AdminLTE./plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.date.extensions',
  'AdminLTE./plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker',
  'AdminLTE./plugins/datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR',
],
['block' => 'script']);
?>
<?php $this->start('scriptBottom'); ?>
<script>
  $(function () {
    //Datemask yyyy-mm-dd
    $(".datepicker")
        .inputmask("yyyy-mm-dd", {"placeholder": "yyyy-mm-dd"})
        .datepicker({
            language:'en',
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });
  });
</script>
<script>
    $('#order_id').autocomplete({ 
             delay: 0,
             minLength: 2,
        source:'<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Orders', 'action' => 'search')); ?>'
        });
</script>
<script>
        $('#supplier').autocomplete({ 
             delay: 0,
             minLength: 3,
        source:'<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Suppliers', 'action' => 'search')); ?>'

        });
</script>
<script>
document.getElementById('supplier').addEventListener('change',function(){
       var supplier_name = this.value;
       //alert(supplier_name);
        var csrfToken = $('[name=_csrfToken]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "Suppliers", "action" => "fill")); ?>',
            headers: {          
           Accept: "application/json"  
                },  
            data: {'supplier_name' : supplier_name},
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
               xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrfToken);
            },
            success: function(data){
                //alert(data);
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "OptionChanges", "action" => "getExchangeRate")); ?>',
                            headers: {          
                           Accept: "application/json"  
                                },  
                            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                               xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrfToken);
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                //alert(data);
                                data = JSON.parse(data);
                                document.getElementById('rate').value = data.value;
                            }
                            });
                if(data != null){
                    document.getElementById('id').value = data.id;
                    //alert("id: " + data.id);
                    if(data.country_id != '' && data.country_id != 157){

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "OptionChanges", "action" => "getCustomsRate")); ?>',
                            headers: {          
                           Accept: "application/json"  
                                },  
                            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                               xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrfToken);
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                //alert(data);
                                data = JSON.parse(data);
                                document.getElementById('customs').value = data.value;
                            }
                            });

                            $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "OptionChanges", "action" => "getBankCharges")); ?>',
                            headers: {          
                           Accept: "application/json"  
                                },  
                            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                               xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrfToken);
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                //alert(data);
                                data = JSON.parse(data);
                                document.getElementById('bank').value = data.value;
                            }
                            });



                    }
                }
            else{
                    alert("Invalid supplier name please verify name or create a new supplier")
                    document.getElementById('supplier').value = "";
                    document.getElementById('id').value = "";


                }

            }
        });

    });
</script>
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
    //alert('ready');
    var csrfToken = $('[name=_csrfToken]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "InwardShipments", "action" => "getLatest")); ?>',
        headers: {          
       Accept: "application/json"  
            },  
        beforeSend: function(xhr){  
           xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrfToken);
        },
        success: function(data){
            //alert(data);
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if(isNaN(data.release_note)){
                document.getElementById('note').value = parseInt(data.release_note.slice(0, -1)) + 1;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('note').value = parseInt(data.release_note) + 1;
            }

        }
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
$('#comercial').change(function(){
    document.getElementById('note').value = (document.getElementById('note').value + 'C');

    });
</script>

<?php $this->end(); ?>
```

This is my create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE `inward_shipments` (
  `release_note` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_method_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `freight_amount` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplier_invoice_number` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplier_release_note` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_total` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `comercial` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `consignment_no` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dim_l` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dim_w` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dim_h` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `volumetric` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `freight_invoice_no` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `USD_exch_rate` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `freight_costs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `customs_costs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `freight_added` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `certification_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bank_charges` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `other_charges` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`release_note`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is the error message I always get as you can see release_note isn't even in the Insert statement.
[image]

What the site looks like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you're unable to use VARCHAR as a  primary key in CakePHP you may only have auto increment integers and CHAR(36) UUID.

In a way the release notes are auto increment but some of them had C on the end for commercial.
I solved this by just making the primary key an int and auto incrementing it.

Comment: It should be possible to use any kind of column type for the primary key, CakePHP shouldn't care, which however doesn't mean that you should do it, a `VARCHAR` primary key surely comes with drawbacks. The problem more likely was that the value wasn't being submitted given that the input is disabled, or, in case you were doing something in order for the value to be sent, it wasn't allowed to be mass assigned.

Comment: @ndm I changed from 'release_note' => false to 'release_note' => true in the entity file and got rid of disabled and now it seems to work is there any way I could disable the field to editing and have this still work?

Comment: You could submit the value via a separate hidden field instead, and use a differently named disabled input for display purposes only.

Comment: alright that sounds like a good way also just tried another way with css pointer-events: none. Thanks for your help.